# Android app hides when tries to get image from device sources

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have android app created by Android studio with standard Navigation Drawer Activity pattern. On one of my fragments layout i have imageview, which allows users to load image from device when they tap it. There is a fragment code:

```
public class ProfileFragment extends Fragment implements FieldsDisplay {

private ProfileViewModel profileViewModel;
private TextView tvBirthDate;
private TextView tvEmail;
private EditText etAddress;
private EditText etName;
private EditText etPhone;
private ImageView avatar;
View root;

private Person currentUser;

private Button btnChangePass;
private ImageButton btnEditData;
private Button btnCommitChanges;

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    profileViewModel =
            new ViewModelProvider(this).get(ProfileViewModel.class);
    root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
    tvEmail = root.findViewById(R.id.tvUserEmail);
    tvBirthDate = root.findViewById(R.id.tvBirthDate);

    etAddress = root.findViewById(R.id.etUserAddress);
    etName = root.findViewById(R.id.etUserName);
    etPhone = root.findViewById(R.id.etPhone);

    avatar = root.findViewById(R.id.imgAvatar);
    avatar.setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, 1);
    });


    btnChangePass = root.findViewById(R.id.btnChangePassword);
    btnCommitChanges = root.findViewById(R.id.btnCommitChanges);
    btnEditData = root.findViewById(R.id.btnChangeUserData);

    btnEditData.setOnClickListener(v -> allowDataChanges());
    btnChangePass.setOnClickListener(v -> updatePassword());
    btnCommitChanges.setOnClickListener(v -> commitChanges());


    Drawable drawable = (btnEditData.getDrawable());
    if (drawable != null) {
        drawable.mutate();
        drawable.setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.dark_blue), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
    }

    update();

    return root;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        Uri chosenImageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap mBitmap;
        try {
            mBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), chosenImageUri);
            avatar.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
            currentUser.setAvatar(ImgUtils.getBitmapAsByteArray(mBitmap));
            updateCurrentUser();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private void allowDataChanges() {
    btnCommitChanges.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    setFieldsEnabled(true);
}

private void setFieldsEnabled(boolean flag) {
    etName.setEnabled(flag);
    etAddress.setEnabled(flag);
    etPhone.setEnabled(flag);
}

private void updatePassword() {
    DialogBuilderFactory builderFactory = new DialogBuilderFactory(getContext());
    DialogBuilder builder = builderFactory.getDialogBuilder(DialogType.PASSWORD_UPDATE);
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.build(null,
            null, this);
    dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.drawable.light_blue_oval_shape);
    dialog.show();
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private void commitChanges() {
    String fullFio = etName.getText().toString();
    String address = etAddress.getText().toString();
    String phone = etPhone.getText().toString();
    if (!(checkFio(fullFio) && checkAddress(address) && checkPhone(phone)))
        return;

    currentUser.setAddress(address);
    currentUser.setFio(fullFio);
    currentUser.setTelephone(phone);
    updateCurrentUser();
    setFieldsEnabled(false);
    btnCommitChanges.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

private boolean checkFio(String fullFio) {
    String[] fio = fullFio.split(" ");
    if (fio.length != 3) {
        showError(getString(R.string.fio_ex));
        return false;
    }
    for (String s : fio) {
        if (s.isEmpty()) {
            showError(getString(R.string.empty_fio_ex));
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean checkAddress(String address) {
    if (address.isEmpty()) {
        showError(getString(R.string.addr_ex));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private boolean checkPhone(String phone) {
    if (!phone.matches("\\+375[\\d]{9}")) {
        showError(getString(R.string.phone_ex));
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

private void updateCurrentUser(){
    Completable.fromAction(this::updateUser)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {
                    //Do your stuff here
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {

                }
            });
}

private void updateUser(){
    new PersonDao().update(currentUser);
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
@Override
public void update() {
    Completable.fromAction(() -> currentUser = FBUtils.getCurrentUserAsPerson())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            etPhone.setText(currentUser.getTelephone());
            etName.setText(currentUser.getFio());
            etAddress.setText(currentUser.getAddress());
            tvEmail.setText(currentUser.getLogin());
            tvBirthDate.setText(LocalDateTimeHelper.getFormattedDate(currentUser.getBirthday()));
            byte[] avatarBytes = currentUser.getAvatar();
            if(avatarBytes!=null) {
                Bitmap imgAvatar = ImgUtils.getByteArrayAsBitmap(avatarBytes);
                avatar.setImageBitmap(imgAvatar);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {

        }
    });

}

private void showError(String message) {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}}
```

But when user selects needed image, the app hides. But, when i put break point on start of my onActivityResult function, i can see, that it performs successfully. When onAcitivityResult starts, this app is already hidden. When i tried to save loaded picture and start app again, picture was saved.
Logs:

```
/Choreographer: Skipped 51 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.  
D/ViewRootImpl@b182484[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl@b182484[MainActivity]: ViewPostIme pointer 1
D/ViewRootImpl@b182484[MainActivity]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0 1
D/InputMethodManager: prepareNavigationBarInfo() DecorView@67ff46d[MainActivity]
    getNavigationBarColor() -855310
W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0xd135a008 disconnect failed
D/OpenGLRenderer: eglDestroySurface = 0xe4a51480, 0xd135a000
D/ViewRootImpl@b182484[MainActivity]: Relayout returned: old=[0,0][1080,1920] new=[0,0][1080,1920] result=0x5 surface={false 0} changed=true
D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=80
D/ViewRootImpl@b182484[MainActivity]: stopped(true) old=false
```

The only solution i found is to start my actitity again from onActivityResult function, but then my app hides and starts again. How can i return to this fragment after selecting image without app hiding?

Comment: Can you share the rest of the codes in this fragment please?

Comment: shared full code of fragment, but it affects many other classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in stack of onActivityResult calls.
When intent finished its work, onActivityResult on the level of Activity started the first, so when onActivityResult started on the level of fragment, it was already processed.
The solution is to change request code of intent and add checking of it to the activity level, so it will be processed only on the level of fragment.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't run your room database operations on main thread like

```
new UserDao().update(user); //UserDao() is abstract you shouldn't use it too
```

This is the problem. Use RxJava.

```
Completable.fromAction(new Action() {
        @Override
        public void run() throws Exception {
            userViewModel.update(user);
        }
    }).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onSubscribe(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Disposable d) {
            
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete() {
            //Do your stuff here
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(@io.reactivex.annotations.NonNull Throwable e) {
            
        }
    });
```

Comment: i move all my database operations in this fragment to separate threads, but it hasn't solved my problem. Code in issue is updated.

Comment: new UserDao() call is moved to another thread now, but is hasn't solved a problem too. Code is updated

Comment: Stop using Daos you shouldn't use it. If you use "new ..Dao().update()" you will be getting same errors. Do not use it.  When you see anything with Dao().update/delete/insert" Change it with "...ViewModel.update()/delete()/insert()"

Comment: it's true, but there is another problem - when app tries to use dao my app is already hidden on the first line of onActivityResult function. I removed line with Dao from my code and got the same problem

Comment: Can you update with the last codes and Log window please?

Comment: Solution is posted as an anwer, thank you